# Adding colour to a custom eclipse plug in editor which extends text editor

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, plugins, text-editor

I'm currently creating an Eclipse plugin project for XML content assist. My editor currently extends the text editor which generates a black and white colour scheme. Is there any way I can have the normal XML colour scheme while still extending text editor?

Comment: Yes there is but it is far too complex for a SO answer. Read all of the 'Editors' help in the Eclipse help 'Platform Plug-in Developer Guide', particularly the section on 'Syntax Coloring'. If you have a much more specific question you can ask here again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up. The solution was right in front of me. Create a new plug-in project in Eclipse with the 'editor' template or else use the extension wizard found in plugin.xml. There are pre developed classes which use text editor combined with colour. Very easy to reference or to build upon.